# Laravel Mix LiveReload doesn't work with Valet .test domain

Tags: laravel, webpack

I run my Laravel app locally with Valet (with the secure option with https) on `https://example.test`. When I follow [the instructions](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/livereload):

`npm install webpack-livereload-plugin@1 --save-dev`

And put the following in `webpack.mix.js`

```js
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');

mix.webpackConfig({
    plugins: [new LiveReloadPlugin()]
});
```

And then put this in my Blade file

```php
@env('local')
  <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
@endenv
```

And then run `npm run watch` (the docs say `npx mix watch` but I guess that's the same?) nothing happens. I guess that's because the URL `http://localhost:35729/livereload.js` is incorrect? There's nothing in the docs that explains how this works with Valet.

I have also tried the instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094694/1833562)

Add `mix.browserSync('example.test');` to `webpack.mix.js`. But when I then `npm run watch` it opens `localhost:8080`?

Not sure what I need to do to get a live reload to work.